# Detecting user with VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to delete a file on my computer using vb. That bit is fine

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load()

Kill ("C:\User\myname\file.txt")
```

For example, that would delete that file no harm done.

However, what If I sent this program to someone else, I wouldn't know their username so I could delete that file because the don't know the path

How can I solve this?

Thanks for any answers,

Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim fil as String
fil = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\file.Text"

 ' or Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData

My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(fil)
```

`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` automatically resolves to the current user's AppData folder, so all you need to do is append the actual filename.

Answer (score 1):

Exists a lot of ways to get the current username, an easy way is expanding the `UserName` environment variable:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERNAME%")
```

But if you are using a static path in your application then you should consider to use the `UserProfile` value of the `SpecialFolder` Enumeration which represents this path:

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}
```

...and then combine the path:

```
IO.Path.Combine( _
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), _
   "file.txt")
```

As result you will obtain this path: `C:\User\{USERNAME}\file.txt`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, both of the given answers are fine thank you